# Is there a way to manipulate 'inner stroke' of SVG using css?

Tags: css, svg, fill, stroke

I have the following rating stars SVGs that I need to manipulate by css:

[image: rating stars]
For each variant (full, half, empty) a different SVG is used. The full ones are easy to style:

```
stroke: $dark-yellow;
fill: $light-yellow;
```

In order to avoid this 'double border effect', for the empty one I'm using:

```
stroke: none;
fill: $dark-yellow;
```

I have no clue how to avoid the 'double border' in the half empty star. Any hints or clues are very much appreciated.

Ah, and for SVGs we use a library, so I'm not sure if I can manipulate the SVG itself.
This is how the half star looks like there:

```
<symbol id="icon-star-half" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path d="M31.303 13.766c0.303-0.294 0.414-0.653 0.306-0.985s-0.409-0.556-0.826-0.617l-9.19-1.335c-0.231-0.034-0.559-0.272-0.662-0.481l-4.109-8.326c-0.187-0.379-0.494-0.596-0.842-0.596s-0.655 0.218-0.842 0.596l-4.109 8.327c-0.103 0.209-0.431 0.448-0.662 0.481l-9.189 1.335c-0.418 0.061-0.719 0.286-0.827 0.617s0.004 0.691 0.306 0.985l6.649 6.481c0.167 0.163 0.292 0.549 0.253 0.778l-1.57 9.152c-0.073 0.426 0.062 0.694 0.189 0.844 0.157 0.187 0.384 0.29 0.639 0.29 0.174 0 0.354-0.048 0.535-0.143l8.219-4.322c0.096-0.051 0.249-0.081 0.409-0.081s0.313 0.030 0.409 0.081l8.219 4.321c0.446 0.235 0.908 0.168 1.173-0.146 0.126-0.15 0.262-0.418 0.189-0.844l-1.569-9.153c-0.039-0.229 0.086-0.614 0.253-0.777l6.649-6.482zM23.288 21.217l1.504 8.773-7.878-4.142c-0.161-0.085-0.354-0.14-0.558-0.172v-22.047l3.563 7.22c0.266 0.54 0.917 1.012 1.512 1.098l8.809 1.28-6.374 6.213c-0.43 0.421-0.679 1.185-0.577 1.778z"></path>
</symbol>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use one SVG? You can have the "half" shape hidden or change it's stroke and fill to `$light-yellow` on full stars, and for the empty star change those to none/white.

Comment: @disinfor thanks for your reply. Actually I'm not sure, why 3 different SVGs are used here. But how would I hide the "half" shape of the full star in terms of css?

Comment: If you can't change the SVG there is little we can do.